# Angular2 bind to -moz-transform

Tags: angular, binding, styles

I want to bind to `WebkitTransform`, `-moz-tranform` ...

I assume that something like `[style.-moz-transform]` is illegal since the variable starts with `-`.

Is there a way to do this? - In addition is there a list of all bindable expressions?

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: to manipulate it inside the model

Comment: Why not just bind to transform? Why do you want to bind to the prefixed version ? Because firefox currently has great support without usage of the prefix.

Comment: if i remeber correctly something did not work out... but it may be different now